# How to pass array of objects to laravel controller through ajax?

Tags: jquery, arrays, laravel

I am into an interesting problem and that is I am unable to pass an array of objects to the laravel controller.
Every known method seems to get fail.. When I do console.log, array seems to like this:

```
parts []
0: {ETag: ""66b0b95edc0079f467657ba663017626"", PartNumber: 1}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But whenever I pass the array to the controller, I get an empty array.
This is how I am passing :

```
var a = JSON.stringify(parts);

    $.ajax({   
    url: "http://cineplus.local/api/movie/verifyUpload", 
    data: {
      'parts': a,
      
    },
```

If I don't do JSON.stringify(), dd($request->all) don't even show parts to be recieved.
Any insights on how to deal with it?

Comment: Try this `'parts': $.serialize(a),`

Comment: Do a `json_decode` on the server side to get the stringified data as array

Comment: First check value exist `console.log(a) `

Comment: @A.ANoman yes value exsist

Comment: @linktoahref json decode got null as well

Comment: use `dataType:'JSON'`